# Which FileStream constructor is identical to CreateFile()?

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to use a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the same way I use a [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so which `FileStream` constructor gives me the control on all of `CreateFile()` arguments? I think that this is the correct one:

```
FileStream(String, FileMode, FileSystemRights, FileShare, Int32, FileOptions, FileSecurity)
```

---

***Edit:*** I just want to know which constructor allows me to set all of the parameters supported by the underlying CreateFile().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to know which constructor allows me to set all of the parameters supported by the underlying CreateFile().

None of them do that. For instance:

- `FileStream` doesn't support the full range of devices that `CreateFile` does.
- Not all possible `dwFlagsAndAttributes` values can be specified via `FileStream`.
- The `hTemplateFile` parameter is not available via `FileStream`.
- There are likely more items that could be added to this list.

`FileStream` is less capable than `CreateFile` and only exposes partial functionality.